# Gnu's reverse_iterator<Iterator>::operator-> and proxy iterators

Tags: c++, gcc, iterator, c++14, reverse-iterator

I have realized that, according to the C++-14 standard in  [[reverse.iter.opref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/reverse.iter.opref), the `reserver_iterator<Iterator>::operator->` must be equivalent to:

```
return std::addressof(operator*());
```

while in C++11 ([link to same section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/reverse.iter.opref)) was:

```
return &(operator*());
```

`std::addressof` was added in C++11, so, it could be used here. I think it maybe be just a defect that was corrected later.

However, the GLIBCXX's implementation of the reverse iterator (version 6.2.0 of gcc), follows the pre-C++14 definition:

```
// /usr/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:174
{ return &(operator*()); }
```

The use of `operator&` in that sentence allows proxy iterators to overload `operator&` on the `reference` type to give their iterators the correct semantics, if they need it. So, maybe gcc is not assuming the `reference` will be a real reference for the forward iterator case, as the standard mandates.

Is gcc explicitely allowing proxy iterators (they usually work after all)? Do other compilers do the same thing?

Comment: So the alternatives are 1) GCC implemented the C++98 specification and didn't get to change it to match C++14's specification yet; or 2) GCC "explicitly" but apparently silently implemented an extension that's documented nowhere, that depends on the widely frowned upon practice of overloading unary `operator&`, and that breaks conforming C++14 code. Hmm, I know which one I'd pick.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, it's sounds conspiranoid, but, otherwise, proxy iterators could stop working. More than adding an extension (yes!, overload `operator&` on proxy iterators's `reference` without specifying an extra option to the compiler!), I say that maybe it was keep unchanged to don't break old trickery. Proxy iterators are explicitely disallowed by the standard but are a requested feature anyway (like me, that I don't know where to find to be sure my proxy will work). I was just reading some STL implementations to see exactly how iterators are used, and I found that.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `&` in `std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>::operator->` was marked as a library defect in [2188](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2188), and the change introduced in C++14.

But still, that change wasn't satifactory, because `std::reverse_iterator` requires a bidirectional iterator, and it doesn't forbid proxy pointers (no iterator concept forbid it). Although the forward iterators' `reference` must be a real reference, the same doesn't apply to the `pointer` type: it doesn't need to be a `pointer` to value type, and it can be a proxy pointer.

So, there's another library issue, still open, without consensous about how to fix that: [1052](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1052). Maybe that issue is what made gcc don't change the implementation of the `operator->` (or maybe they just forget it).